# If a linear transformation preserves all angles, is it necessarily unitary?

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that if something is unitary, then it preserves the norms and cosines of the angles as the dot product is not changed. I also know that its converse is true, where if something preserves its norms and cosine of its angles then it is unitary. When a linear transformation preserves all angles, is it necessarily unitary? I know that if a linear transformation preserves all lengths, it is unitary due to isometry.

Comment: Your second sentence is not quite true: it can be unitary or anti-unitary (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiunitary_operator). A linear transformation that preserves angles can be a scalar multiple of an orthogonal or unitary (over the real or the complex numbers respectively) transformation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a linear transformation that preserves all angles but changes lengths and thus is non-unitary: Scaling by a constant non-1 factor.